# Send file to Windows CE device over FTP

Tags: windows, windows-ce

I know this will sound weird, but I have a customer who pretends to send files to a Windows CE device from a Windows PC through FTP protocol. Now, my question is, has anybody found a way to configure an FTP server on a Windows CE device so that it can handle incoming FTP calls ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Windows CE provides an FTP server as an optional component. The code is also available, so you can use it to build a customized server (I did that in the past to generate "virtual" folders with logs from a database so users could dowload a csv file that was actually generated on request).
I don't remember if that was included in the base license for the OS or required the "pro" one.
If you just need to receive files you can use the standard server and have your application monitoring the "incoming" folder to process the files (if this is required).

Comment: Which server do you mean ? Thanks

Comment: As I said, the one provided with Windows CE. If you have platform builder it should be in the "Servers" folder of the catalog. You should have also the source code under WINCE600 or WINCE700\public\servers\ftpd IIRC (I don't have WinCE dev environment on the PC I am currently using).